# Does DotNetOpenAuth support Windows Phone projects?

Tags: windows-phone-7, dotnetopenauth

I get this error:

```
Could not install package 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core 4.1.0.12182'. You are trying to install this package into a project that target
s 'Silverlight,Version=v4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone71', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that fram
ework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

I know what the error message says, but it makes no sence - only if this aint suppose to work on Windows Phone at all. I've tried with a WP7 7.0 project but same result...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DotNetOpenAuth does not currently support Windows Phone.