# Kinda confused on how to use Google Api. Stuck with Oauth

Tags: c#, .net, google-api

I am not sure if there any libraries(if anyone knows any please let me know) out there that make it easier to use googles api. I know they have classes for .net but they don't seem to work with Windows Phone 7.

I am trying to figure out how it all works but I really find Google's documentation confusion and missing lots of steps.

I decided to try to at first to use their library in an asp.net mvc application before trying to figure out how to do it all with REST requests in a WP7 app.

I am stuck at trying to figure out how to do the Oauth to validation user so I can get their contacts.

```
 RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings("<var>Test</var>");
            settings.OAuth2Parameters = new OAuth2Parameters
            {
                ClientId = "",
                ClientSecret = "",

            };

            // Need some Code here to validation user so I can then get their contacts.

            ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);
            var c = cr.GetGroups();
```

Comment: Twitter also uses Oauth, for a second reference point you could poke around in their documentation https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an OAuth NuGet package ([DotNetOpenAuth](https://nuget.org/packages/DotNetOpenAuth)) available, providing authentication through Google, Twitter, Facebook, MSN and possibly more.

Maybe you have more luck with that.

Comment: I used that before but I don't think it works on windows phone 7.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't, but I never developed for WinPhone7 before, so I can't really say.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374793/does-dotnetopenauth-support-windows-phone-projects